# TypeError: getState is not a function when adding middleware to Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

Using this code in my configureStore.dev.js file, I get an `Uncaught TypeError: getState is not a function` when adding `applyMiddleware(reduxImmutableStateInvariant)`.  When I remove this added middleware, my project runs fine.  What is the proper way to add this middleware?  Here is the full file:

```
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    // Add other middleware on this line...
    applyMiddleware(reduxImmutableStateInvariant),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f // add support for Redux dev tools
    )
  );

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers').default; // eslint-disable-line global-require
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**reduxImmutableStateInvariant** is a function that you need to call before passing it into applyMiddleware.

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
        // Add other middleware on this line...
        applyMiddleware(reduxImmutableStateInvariant()),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f // add support for Redux dev tools
    )
);
```

---

## Where is this in the docs?

In the github [README docs](https://github.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant), is called after being imported (via require) `reduxImmutableStateInvariant`. See the third line, below:

```
// Be sure to ONLY add this middleware in development!
const middleware = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ?
  [require('redux-immutable-state-invariant')(), thunk] :
  [thunk];

// Note passing middleware as the last argument to createStore requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);
```

---

## Why isn't thunk a function, though?

In the thunk middleware, the thunk function is [called before it is returned](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/41aefcc28a80d2b21f8ee1e68639757bf6d7ba49/src/index.js#L11).

```
const thunk = createThunkMiddleware();
thunk.withExtraArgument = createThunkMiddleware;

export default thunk;
```

---

## So why is redux-immutable-state-invariant a function?

Based on the code, it looks like you can pass in a function (`isImmutable`), that is used to determine which properties in your redux state are immutable. I think that providing your own isImmutable function is what allows this middleware to work nicely with other immutable libraries.

```
export default function immutableStateInvariantMiddleware(isImmutable = isImmutableDefault) {
```

That method is used here
https://github.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant/blob/5ed542246e32b7eec06879b25e5a0a478daf4892/src/trackForMutations.js#L5